# My Console will only return two inputs or just one

Tags: javascript

This is my first time posting, I am having issues getting all selections to generate on the console. If I capitalise rock at the bottom it will only show the "Scissor" result. If I do not capitalise it, it will only show the other two results, but not scissors. Any guidance would be helpful.

```
function computerPlay() {
    let selection = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
    let computerSelection = selection[Math.floor(Math.random() * selection.length)];
    return computerSelection;
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    if (playerSelection === "Rock") {
        if (computerSelection === "Scissors")
            return "You win mate, cheers!";
    } else if (computerSelection === "Paper") {
        return "You lost lad";
    } else {
        return "Draw";
    }
}
const playerSelection = "rock"
const computerSelection = computerPlay()
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if the player selection matches "Rock", you ignore the `else if` and `else` blocks and go to see if the computer selected Scissors. If that is the case you return "You win mate, cheers!", otherwise you don't return anything, that's why you are getting undefined. If the player does not play Rock then you go into either else if or else statement but the player never wins.

Here's what your playRound function might look like to work properly:

```
function playRound(player, comp) {
    const selection = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];

  pl = selection.indexOf(player);
  co = selection.indexOf(comp);

  if (co === pl) { 
    return 'Draw';
  } else if (co - pl == 1) { 
    return 'You lost lad' 
  } else { 
    return 'You win mate, cheers!' 
  }
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle with a working code sample: https://jsfiddle.net/qjp1y1mg/

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me. Try this. It is your code, but something was wrong (a bracket in a wrong place) and I have changed it.

```
    function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
        if (playerSelection === "Rock"){
             if (computerSelection === "Scissors") 
                  return "You win mate, cheers!";

              else if (computerSelection === "Paper"){        
                   return "You lost lad";
             }
            else {return "Draw";}
         }
      }
```

In your code this bracket was wrong. Because you are excluding other occurrences

```
   if (playerSelection === "Rock") {
           if (computerSelection === "Scissors")
                return "You win mate, cheers!";
         **}**
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a curly bracket after the first inner if statement. The indentation of the code should be a sign that it is not nested the way you want it.

```
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) { 
    if (playerSelection === "Rock") { 
        if (computerSelection === "Scissors"{ 
            return "You win mate, cheers!"; 
        } else if (computerSelection === "Paper") { 
            return "You lost lad"; 
        } else { 
            return "Draw"; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Here it is fixed. In future scan through your code and ask yourself which opening brackets correspond to whch closing brackets.